# Can I validate data type,case,length and empty check for XML elements against XSD?

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I've a requirement to validate the XML file. The XML element should pass all the below conditions below.

1. Data type
2. Case
3. Length
4. Empty

Can all the above be done against XSD? I'm trying to validate this in Java API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you can do that. XSD provides data types, like string, int and all.

For `case` and `empty`, XSD provides an option to validate with regular expression, you can use that to adhere to defined expression.

`Length` also can easily be set in XSD.